Understanding the Role of Dummy Variables in Categorical Regression Models
In a categorical regression model with $k$ categories, we use $k-1$ dummy variables. I understand that the $k$-th dummy variable is redundant because the information from the first $k-1$ dummies is sufficient.
$$y_1 = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_{i1} + \beta_2 x_{i2} + ... + \beta_{k-1} x_{i(k-1)} + \epsilon_i$$

Does this mean we get complete information about the $k$-th category iff all $x_{ij} = 0$ for$ j = 1, ..., k-1$?
Must it be that no two or more dummies are equal to 1 simultaneously? If they did, wouldn't that lead to a situation where we lack information about the $k$-th category due to point (1)?
Is it a rule to have exactly $k-1$ dummy variables, or can it be fewer?


to answer your questions,

for your given equation y1=β1xi1+β2xi2+...+βk−1xi(k−1)+ϵi if xij is 0 then yes that does mean that it is answered

for 2 and 3 questions:-  when u work towards categorical values it is mostly dependent upon the need so based on that need we choose the regression model.



Linear regression for metrics and numeric variables and logistic for nominal or ordinal


when u are taking the dummy variables it is the rule that no of dummy variables is always characteristics - 1 because one of the three independent variables becomes redundant and u only need 2 so therefore:-

there is no rule in dummy variables that there cannot be more than '1' based 1 variables, in dummy variables

0 means positive and 1 means negative

if u find that a value is 0 and the other 2 variables are 1 the regression model would choose the other two to have better model accuracy and for your understanding

assume that there are 3 independent variables then k value of would be 4


Dummy variables (i.e. one hot-encoding) is just one of the methods available to encode a nominal variable. In this method you represent a single $k$-valued categorical variable as a $k-1$-th binary variable vector

I don´t understand what you mean by complete information but indeed the $k$-th category is encoded as all zeros. In the linear regression model you describe the $\beta_{0}$ coefficient would be the coefficient related to this base case

If you are using one-hot encoding then only one of the dummy variables can be equal to one at any one time

It is not a rule to have $k-1$ dummy variables it is simply the way that one-hot encoding chooses to do the encoding. If you don't want to use one-hot encoding you could use fewer dummy variables but you would lose intepretability of the coefficients



